# Automatic variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to create a scoped variable/object with a constructor/destructor (on stack) in Objective-C or will I need to add C++ for this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add C/C++ anywhere, since Objective-C **is** already **C** or **C++**.

You can use scoped variables in any message (function) you want:

```
-(void) myMessage
{
    // default constructor will be called
    MyCPPClass myCPPClassInstance;  // scoped variable of type MyCPPClass class
    myCPPClassInstance.Method(); // using MyCPPClassInstance
    return;
    // destructor will be called after returning
}
```

Do note that you will have to use a file name ending with **.mm** in order to use **C++** in Objective-C. If you just need **C**, then you just variables as you would in any other **C** function.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this for now (C++/.mm) but if that is the only option then I will do this

Comment: That's the only option you have to use C++ with Objective-C++. Not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Want a scoped structure for logging entry and exit of methods

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create a scoped variable/object with a constructor/destructor (on stack) in Objective-C

No.

You can created scoped C variables on the stack (obviously!) but not Objective-C classes.  The concept of constructor/destructor does not exist in Objective-C.

> or will I need to add C++ for this?

Yes.

But it will only work with C++ objects.  I suppose you could create a C++ class to wrap an Objective-C object that allocates the Objective-C object in its constructor and releases (note **not** deallocs) it in the destructor.  However, if you do that you might as well autorelease as soon as you alloc.